# Shopify Theme Ruby Gem Errors

Tags: shopify

Hi there I'm attempting to use the shopify_theme gem to manage local shopify development and utilize version control, however I keep getting the errors below. I've reviewed shopify's API docs along with the readme on the theme gem repo and can't seem to get it to work....

(github repo here: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_theme )

```
Kenneths-MacBook-Pro:anglersden kennethprince$ theme configure xxxxxxxxxxxAPIKEYxxxxxxxxxxxxx PASSWORDETC https://xxxxxxxAPIKEYxxxxxxxxxxxx@TESTSTORE.myshopify.com/admin
  create  config.yml
```

Kenneths-MacBook-Pro:anglersden kennethprince$ theme download

/Users/kennethprince/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141:in

`read_nonblock': Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)

```
from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141:in `rbuf_fill'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1319:in `block in transport_request'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `catch'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `transport_request'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in `request'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1286:in `block in request'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/httparty-0.9.0/lib/httparty/request.rb:81:in `perform'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/httparty-0.9.0/lib/httparty.rb:438:in `perform_request'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/httparty-0.9.0/lib/httparty.rb:385:in `get'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/shopify_theme-0.0.7/lib/shopify_theme.rb:10:in `asset_list'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/shopify_theme-0.0.7/lib/shopify_theme/cli.rb:30:in `download'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor.rb:275:in `dispatch'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/base.rb:425:in `start'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/shopify_theme-0.0.7/bin/theme:24:in `<top (required)>'

from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/theme:19:in `load'
from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/theme:19:in `<main>'
from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

I also tried to connect to the shop using the API, see code below.

```
Kenneths-MacBook-Pro:anglersden kennethprince$ irb
1.9.3-p327 :001 > require 'rubygems'
 => false 
1.9.3-p327 :002 > true
 => true 
1.9.3-p327 :003 > require 'rubygems'
 => false 
1.9.3-p327 :004 > require 'rubygems' true
SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected keyword_true, expecting $end
    from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p327 :005 > true
 => true 
1.9.3-p327 :006 > require 'rubygems'
 => false 
1.9.3-p327 :007 > require 'shopify_api'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- shopify_api
    from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):7
    from /Users/kennethprince/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p327 :008 > puts RUBY_VERSION
1.9.3
 => nil 
1.9.3-p327 :009 >
```

Comment: Not an answer, but have you tried opening on issue with a pointer to this report on the GitHub repo? https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_theme/issues

Comment: Also not an answer, but have you tried the official Shopify Theme Sync app for Mac? http://wiki.shopify.com/Theme_Sync_App It’s pretty much exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the way ruby was installed on my Mac. After installing a new hard drive I installed RVM and Homebrew and everything worked fine.